# problem loading J connector

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the eror when i compile my project which i have developed using java / java application

```
C:\Users\Mn_myles\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CACADEMY\src\cacademy\FormLogin.java:248: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class cacademy.Class
                                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                       ^
C:\Users\Mn_myles\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CACADEMY\src\cacademy\change_password.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class cacademy.Class
                                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                             ^
C:\Users\Mn_myles\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CACADEMY\src\cacademy\change_password.java:89: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class cacademy.Class
                                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                             ^
C:\Users\Mn_myles\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CACADEMY\src\cacademy\change_password.java:408: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class cacademy.Class
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
C:\Users\Mn_myles\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CACADEMY\src\cacademy\database.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class cacademy.Class
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
C:\Users\Mn_myles\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CACADEMY\src\cacademy\frmAdd_Edit_Enrollmentfee.java:214: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Category
location: class cacademy.frmAdd_Edit_Enrollmentfee
        Category=fee_year.getSelectedItem().toString();

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
6 errors
```

Comment: With 12 questions asked and no answers accepted, you're not giving anyone a reason to help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the first 5 errors, it looks like you might have a class or variable named `Class` somewhere in your code that is covering up `java.lang.Class`, which is what you want. Try changing those to `java.lang.Class.forName("...");` and see what you get.

Without more information, you're on your own for the 6th error. You haven't given us any context. Do you have an actual variable named `Category` anywhere, or are you missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @T. Yates says, it is a bad style to declare classes with names that are the same as widely used Java classes.  It results in "mysterious" compilation errors, and in other people misreading your code.

I'd avoid reusing any names declared in (at least) `java.lang`, `java.io`, `java.util` and `java.net`, along with the common classes used in AWT, Swing, JDBC and a few other subsystems.